# Python 3.x - don't count carriage returns with len

Tags: python-3.x, string-length

I'm writing the following code as part of my practice:

```
input_file = open('/home/me/01vshort.txt', 'r')
file_content = input_file.read()
input_file.close()
file_length_question = input("Count all characters (y/n)? ")
if file_length_question in ('y', 'Y', 'yes', 'Yes', 'YES'):
    print("\n")
    print(file_content, ("\n"), len(file_content) - file_content.count(" "))
```

It's counting carriage returns in the output, so for the following file (01vshort.txt), I get the following terminal output:

```
Count all characters (y/n)? y

0
0 0
1 1 1

 9
```

...or...

```
Count all characters (y/n)? y

0
00
111

 9
```

In both cases, the answer should be 6, as there are 6 characters, but I'm getting 9 as the result.

I've made sure the code is omitting whitespace, and have tested this with my input file by deliberately adding whitespace and running the code with and without the line:

```
 - file_content.count(" ")
```

Can anyone assist here as to why the result is 9 and not 6?

Perhaps it isn't carriage returns at all?

I'm also curious as to why the result of 9 is indented by 1 whitespace? The input file simply contains the following (with a blank line at the end of the file, line numbers indicated in the example):

```
1. 0
2. 0 0
3. 1 1 1
4.
```

...or...

```
1. 0
2. 00
3. 111
4.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore all whitespace characters including tabs and newlines and other control characters:

```
print(sum(not c.isspace() for c in file_content))
```

will give you the `6` you expect.

Alternatively you can take advantage of the fact the `.split()` method with no argument will split a string on any whitespace character. So split it into non-space chunks and then join them all back together again without the whitespace characters:

```
print(len(''.join(file_content.split())))
```

Comment: I've had time to process and implement this now. I particularly like the elegance of the .splitt() method, especially when combined with the sys.stdout method, which enables skipping commas to account for 'print' sensitivity to this type of character (comma). So, I can use either: >>
`**sys.stdout.write("%s" % (len("".join(file_content.split()))))**`...to print just the result, or the following: >> `**sys.stdout.write("%s%s%s" % (file_content, ("\n"), len("".join(file_content.split()))))**` ...to print the file contents and result with non-indented formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 9 because the content of the file could be interpreted like:

```
file_content = "0\n0 0\n1 1 1\n"
```

and you're only matching the white spaces (`file_content.count(" ")`).

In order to count only the characters you'd either:

- read line by line the file, or
- use a regexp to match white space.

For the indenting of `9`: `print` processes the commas [as outlined here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-March/021345.html)

Comment: Thank you for this. It's been a month since I started Python, and I feel like I'm doing well, but if you could you offer examples for reading line-by-line, as well as regexp, that would be exceptionally useful right now. I find the guidance on this site extremely useful, but it takes me a long time to weave it into my own code.

Comment: ...and re: extra space, thanks. If I split the output line to remove the comma, the problem is solved.